# How to build a docker base image of a new platform by mounting it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I have been trying to create a docker image of a new platform by mounting it in a directory on my Linux machine.

Here are the steps I followed :

1. Mounting the *.img files of the platform in a suitable directory.
2. Modifying the fstab file so that the container image can be mounted as a single partition.
3. Creating a tarball of the mounted filesystem.
4. Doing a **docker import** to import the contents of the tarball to create a docker image of the platform.

However, after bulding the image, I fail to run the container successfully corresponding to the image as I keep receiving following error -

`standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`

Can anyone suggest what's wrong with the process I followed OR any other way to create docker image of the platform from its .img files?

P.S. - I can't use utilities like Debootstrap on my platform so methods like those mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/) wont work!!

Comment: What’s your actual goal in doing this?  Most Dockerfiles start from a standard Linux distribution image (`alpine`, `debian`, `ubuntu`) and don’t have to wrangle with extremely complicated problems like “libc is missing”.

Comment: I don't want to use a standard image. I want to create a standard image for the platform I m using (Tizen), which also uses a Linux Kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just starting with a scratch image and copying the files in?

```
FROM scratch

COPY /files/ /
```

Comment: Will copying the files fix the problem?  
In the docker image, I need mounted filesystem and then be able to run any application on that platform  (ex - a bash shell of the platform). Copying won't achieve that I guess :(

Comment: In that case I don't quite understand what you're trying to do... I thought you were trying to create a new base image from a set of files?

Comment: Ok! Then say i have a virtual machine on which i have my platform running. Is there any way to create a docker image of that platform?

Comment: No, VM images and Docker images are different, and run different bits of software in different simulated environments.

Comment: @DavidMaze I know they're different. But I've found quite a few links on the net where people have generated images of running machines using some utility (ex - see this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s948NKa1I1I) ) . However, all of the stuff I've got are for standard Linux distributions. So, I want to know whether it is possible to generate docker image of non-standard linux platforms (Tizen in my case).